# unchecked or unsafe operations. Recompile with -xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: java

I am aware that there is number of similar posts. The error, as i understand, means that i should be more specific with types. My code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Storefront {
    private  LinkedList<Item> catalog = new LinkedList<Item>();

    public void addItem(String id, String name, String price, String quant) {
         Item it = new Item(id, name, price, quant);
         catalog.add(it);
    }

    public Item getItem(int i) {
            return (Item)catalog.get(i);
    }

    public int getSize() {
         return catalog.size();
    }

    //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void sort() {
        Collections.sort(catalog);
    }
}
```

However, I do specify that `LinkedList` consists of objects of type `Item`. When i compile it with -xlint, i get

---

```
warning: unchecked method invocation: method sort in class
Collections is applied to given types
Collections.sort(catalog);

required: List'<'T'>'

found: LinkedList'<'Item'>'

where T is a type-variable:
T extends Comparable'<'? super T'>' declared in method 
'<'T'>'sort'<'List'<'T'>'>
```

---

As i understand, `LinkedList` implements `List` and `Item` implements `Comparable`. So, aren't 'required' and 'found' same?

Also I was checking if `catalog.get(i);` is actually an Item (as, some say it may have caused the problem), but it produced the same error.

Comment: Side comment: you shouldn't need a cast in `return (Item)catalog.get(i);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get this warning if your `Item` class implements `Comparable` and not `Comparable<Item>`. Make sure your `Item` class is defined like this:

```
class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
```

Comment: Don't forget to do a "compareTo(Item I)" (or similar) instead of generic "Object".  It's real easy to forget to do that when going back and updating old code.